# Why is the algorithm for modular exponentiation by squaring considered as poly time?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

As the [link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) on Wikipedia says, and I have read it in many other books as well, if we use squaring in exponentiation for modular exponentiation the complexity reduces and cuts down to $O(\log n)$, where $n$ is the exponent.

1. What I do not get here is that when we are using modular exponentiation modulo $p$, why aren't we taking into account that modulo when calculating the complexity? For larger numbers, if we keep on taking squares until we reach $n$ the resulting number will be extremely huge, so we have to compute modulo $p$ at almost every step. Now shouldn't that increase the complexity? Or im wrong in assuming that we need to take mod at every step?

   Can we do this squaring in the exponentiation process for any base like $6$ or $10$ or we have to stick with $2$?

Comment: Computing $x^2 \bmod p$ is assumed to be a single operation that takes constant time. For example, one could just look up the multiplication table, which has only $p^2$ entries and can be precomputed.

Comment: It does increase the amount of work to be done, but for a fixed $p$ that can absorbed into the big Oh.For variable $p$ you can include a factor that is a power of $\log p$ to take this into account. A further point is that here $p$ and $n$ typically are approximately the same size, so any power of $\log p$ is still polynomial. Also observe that performing that modular exponentiation by some other recipe is similarly affected, so for the purposes of comparing different algorithms we can ignore that factor.

Comment: The base, exponent and p are all fixed, but in my case the base belongs to the range 2-10, the exponent is a factor of (p-1) and hence strictly less than p, so even then this mod p wont be affecting the poly nature of the algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

You do need to work modulo p at each step. Let's say you are doing $x^m$ with $m$ being $b+1$ bits long. You write this as a product of some of $x^{2^b} \cdots x^{2^1}, x^{2^0}$ where the positions of the 1 bits in m tell you which ones to use. Going from $x^{2^k}$ to $x^{2^{k+1}}$ is squaring modulo p. So to get all of them you need you have to do $b$ squaring operations. Then you have to multiply some of these together. Say there are $l$ 1 bits in $m$. That means an additional $l$ multiplications modulo $p$. A total of $b+l$ but that is approximately proportional to $\log m$ not $m$.

Comment: In squaring modulo p, wont the size of p affect the runtime complexity in term of big O notation if m is a factor of (p-1), i.e to say that m is strictly less than p? Or is the mod function not as complex as im assuming even for large values of p, say like integers with 60-80 digits?

Answer (score 0):

1. They are not ignoring the complexity of working mod $p$ at all.  They are simply measuring the complexity of the algorithm in units of multiplications mod $p$.  The time complexity of doing a multiplication mod $p$ is a separate and well-studied question and it would be pointless to mix the two together (well, almost pointless: some multiplications could be less expensive than the worst case and maybe we could somehow exploit that consistently and bring down the total complexity).

The time complexity of multiplication modulo $p$ is also polynomial in the number of bits of $p$ (naively $O(\log^2 p)$, but can be done more efficiently with better algorithms), so even multiplying the number of multiplications by the cost of each one makes the time complexity polynomial in the size of the input.

If you think about it, this abstraction is actually a wise strategy, because it means the estimate can be immediately updated if ever there is an improvement to the complexity of multiplication.  In fact this is one reason why the Wikipedia article separates out multiplication and squaring, because in some contexts squaring might be accomplished more easily than arbitrary multiplication.  A more natural example is in computational linear algebra where I believe the optimal complexity of matrix multiplication is still an open problem: it would be practical to state the complexity of an algorithm in units of matrix multiplications.

2. Base 2 is particularly well-suited to computer implementation, but nothing is stopping you from computing $x^{35}$ by computing $x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^{10}, x^{20}, x^{30}$ and then combining $x^5$ and $x^{30}$ (which is a base-10 decomposition of the exponent).  In practice you will probably find bases much higher than $2$ to be less efficient in terms of number of multiplications, but only by a constant factor for any given base.  In fact it is a separate question to determine the least number of multiplications needed to get to an exponent $n$ (no base is optimal for this in general).

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain why in factoring we have $14^{105} \bmod 5 = (((14^3)^5)^7)$. Then we have $14^3\equiv 4\ mod\ 5$, then $4^5\equiv 4\ mod\ 5$?

Comment: @Avra Your question is very unclear and not relevant to this question or answer.  Why don’t you just post it as an actual new question so everyone has the opportunity to answer it?  If so, you should also detail very precisely **where** your understanding begins and ends.  A question like “here are 20 steps I don’t even understand what any of the symbols mean please explain” will be strongly frowned upon.